# Why does `Function.prototype` only return a reference to `Function` in the console?

Tags: javascript

Why does `Function.prototype` only return a reference to `Function`? It seems the equivalent of the `constructor` property that is in `Object.prototype`. I was expecting all the properties that're available to functions AND the properties that're available in `Object.prototype` to be stored in a further `__proto__` object.

[image]

Comment: This might be more of a [tag:chrome] question. Firefox does allow you to see the properties of `Function.prototype` in the JavaScript console.

Comment: use `console.dir(Function.prototype)` same when you take a look at DOM Nodes

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks. Any solution to why `new Function` produces an 'EvalError: call to Function() blocked by CSP' on Firefox?

Comment: `new Function()` works perfectly fine for me. If you have issue with it it might have something to do with the parameters you pass to it. However I suggest you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have problems with it, providing more details about the parameters you provide to the constructor.